# MAPITABLE, InstanceKeys and Stores

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-redemption

I understand that the MAPITABLE stores the InstanceKey for each individual
store. I've tried following the examples off the website get this table, but
have not been successful.

My mission is to remove a Store from being monitored in a SortedDictionary when
StoreRemove is called. That way, if it is re-added, there will not be an
exception thrown.

How can i generate the table of Store items properly?

non-working code (can't determine the tables I need):

```
        MAPITable mt = rStores.MAPITable;
        Recordset rs = new Recordset();

        rs = mt.ExecSQL("SELECT EntryID FROM Name");
        while (!(rs.EOF))
        {
            Debug.Print(rs.Fields["EntryID"].Value);
            rs.MoveNext();
        }
```

Comment: Hey Larry - how did you get a Recordset object in C#? What assembly did you reference?

Comment: For anyone wondering how to use Recordset in C#, you need to add a reference to the COM assembly Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects - there's a whole lot of versions - I used 2.1 since I think that's the one that comes with XP, and 6.0 comes with Vista (but I might be wrong)

Comment: @Blakomen - I have to dig up my code.  I finished off this project a while back and forgot to update the information.  Dmitry's advice of where to look was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you need to retrieve the source keys (along with entry ids etc.) first – have you tried RDOStores.MAPITable.ExecSQL?

Comment: i've been storing the EntryIDs in my wrapper.  I haven't tried that yet, as I've been struggling with the docs and trying to convert from VB to C# in my head.  Will go ahead with that and see what I can come up with.

Comment: Is there a list somewhere of the MAPI tables?

Comment: still trying to figure this out, but all I can glean is information from messages, not stores, using ExecSQL.

Comment: also, my searches only bring up message DASL info...nothing related to stores.  I'm very lost in trying to figure this out in order to use a very basic Redemption function.